# VS Code intellisense doesn't show me color box for hex value color

Tags: colors, visual-studio-code, hex, intellisense

When I write CSS, intellisense doesn't show me color box for hex value color but only icon. Before, Intellisense showed me color box for hex value. I don't know why. Now I use VS Code version 1.31.1. Can I change it or exist some extensions?  Below are print screens. Thanks.

[image: Before with color box for hex value]
[image: Now without color box for hex value, only with icon]

Comment: A bug and it's already filed: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/68269

Answer (score 10):

If anyone here is wondering why they no longer see the color box next to their #FFFFF color scheme in vs code, check on the bottom right that it is set to CSS and not say POSTCSS.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Color Highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqDZo.png), you need to go to the extension settings and then change this value:

**From:**

[image]

**To:**

[image]

And that's all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `Color Pick` vscode extension now:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adam-watters.vscode-color-pick

Usage:  After install, press `F1` > enter `pc`